# Get column values for table where checkbox = selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table, with checkbox for each row. Where the row is selected, I would like to get that row's columns value.

```
<table id="tblBrowse">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkboxBrowseSelectAll" value="">
            </th>
            <th>Order No</th>
            <th>Ship To</th>
            <th>Sold To</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td class="sorting_1">1959-01</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- And lots more of the same thing -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can get the checkboxes that are checked, but how do I get the value 123, and 456?

```
$('#btnTest').click(function () {
    var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    // Where do I go from here?
});
```

I can use either jQuery or plain JS, but must be compatible with IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all `checkedBoxes` using `.forEach()` method, then using `.closest("tr")` find the closest table row to that checkbox and then get that row's columns value.

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
checkedBoxes.forEach(chk => {
  chk.closest("tr").querySelectorAll('td:not(:first-child)').forEach((td, index) => {
    console.log(index, td.innerHTML)
  });
})
```

An important thing to note here is the use of `:not(:first-child)` in `.querySelectorAll('td:not(:first-child)')`. This is done so that we can ignore the first column in every row, as that is a checkbox column and we don't need its content for our logic.

Demo:

```js
document.getElementById("btnTest").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  checkedBoxes.forEach(chk => {
    chk.closest("tr").querySelectorAll('td:not(:first-child)').forEach((td, index) => {
      console.log(index, td.innerHTML)
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<button id="btnTest">Get Value</button>
<table id="tblBrowse">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkboxBrowseSelectAll" value="">
      </th>
      <th>Order No</th>
      <th>Ship To</th>
      <th>Sold To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">1959-01</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- And lots more of the same thing -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a value to each check box and store its value in a variable

```
var xyz=checkedBoxes.value;
```

xyz will be an array